# Wordpress Theme not working on live server

Tags: wordpress, themes

I downloaded the 'Tungstenation' theme for Wordpress from padd solutions and i'm trying to install for my wordpress site. However, it seems that on localhost the theme works as per expectations but on live server on activating the theme it returns :

> 500 Internal Server error.

Can anyone please assist me. I tried every method of config, .htaccess changes but in vain.

PHP version on server is 5.3.8

Regards
Younus

Comment: First try to activate debug mode from wp-config.php file, then tell me if you get any PHP errors

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating all of your plugins and see if that works.